# Configuring Spring Boot to Log Tomcat Access Logs with Logback and Logback GELF

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, logback

I'm trying to set up Tomcat access logging for Spring Boot application. I have already tried configuring Logback and the logback-gelf appender for other logging purposes, and they work fine. Also added configuration for STDOUT `logback-access.xml` and it also work fine but with `GelfTcpAppender` its not.

Java 17
SpringBoor 2.7.14
de.siegmar:logback-gelf 4.0.2

This is `logback-access.xml` configuration file.

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="GELF" class="de.siegmar.logbackgelf.GelfTcpAppender">
        <graylogHost>xx.xx.xx.xx</graylogHost>
        <graylogPort>12201</graylogPort>
        <connectTimeout>15000</connectTimeout>
        <socketTimeout>5000</socketTimeout>
        <reconnectInterval>300</reconnectInterval>
        <maxRetries>2</maxRetries>
        <retryDelay>3000</retryDelay>
        <poolSize>2</poolSize>
        <poolMaxWaitTime>5000</poolMaxWaitTime>
        <poolMaxIdleTime>10</poolMaxIdleTime>
        <encoder class="de.siegmar.logbackgelf.GelfEncoder">
            <originHost>localhost</originHost>
            <includeRawMessage>false</includeRawMessage>
            <includeMarker>true</includeMarker>
            <includeMdcData>true</includeMdcData>
            <includeCallerData>false</includeCallerData>
            <includeRootCauseData>false</includeRootCauseData>
            <includeLevelName>false</includeLevelName>
            <shortPatternLayout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%m%nopex</pattern>
            </shortPatternLayout>
            <fullPatternLayout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%m%n</pattern>
            </fullPatternLayout>
            <numbersAsString>false</numbersAsString>
            <staticField>app_name:backend</staticField>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ASYNC GELF" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="GELF"/>
        <neverBlock>true</neverBlock>
    </appender>
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC GELF"/>
</configuration>
```

Does anyone have the correct configuration for `logback-access.xml`?